# Generic Repository with Paging For GetAll Method to include Item Count

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using a generic repository something like Repo which has a method

```
 public IEmerable<TEntity> GetAll(
 Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
 Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
 IList<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes = null,
 int? page = null,
 int? pageSize = null)
 {
        var query = context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.AsExpandable().Where(filter);
        }
        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
        {
            query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1)*pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
        }
        return query.ToList();
 }
```

The problem lies here I am trying to DDD so 'TEntity' is actually **entity class for EF**. I need to return the *total records count* of the total database record as well. How shall I do it following best practises for an API?

Answer (score 2):

If it  is possible you can change you generic repository interface to use value tuples:

```
public (int count, IEnumerable<TEntity> records) GetAll(...){}
```

Or introduce generic DTO:

```
public class CountedResult<TEntity>
{
    public int Count { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Records { get; set;}
}
```

And return it:

```
public CountedResult<TEntity> GetAll(...){}
```

P.S.

Would not it make sense to order stuff after filtering?

Comment: Since the respository is EFRepo<TEntity> that only works with POCO class, I am getting limited to POCO classes as I cannot modify them. So @Guru Stron you are suggesting a Dto class and and do the mapping? Generic Dto not needed do we need it as you mentioned? but in that scenario things are getting very complex like EFRepo<CountedResult<TEntity>>. Can we have something a bit simpler?

Comment: It would still be EFRepo<TEntity> Just the return type of your GetAll() method would reflect the CountedResult<TEntity>.

Comment: @somnathroy as Steve Py said, your repository is still `EFRepo<TEntity>`, but this concrete method returns now `CountedResult<TEntity>` and not `TEntity`.